# How can I achieve gamma correction on images showed in a web browser?

Tags: browser, images, plugins, css, gamma

A lot of images are too dark, especially movie screenshot images, thumbnails or montages. Is it possible to set up a gamma correction value in todays web browsers, maybe with a help of a plugin, or with some custom CSS rules?

Comment: Many graphics drivers today have global color correction options in their respective control panels that are good for this (and can often deliver a higher quality correction curve than you can achieve through software operating on e.g. a 24-bit color space).

Comment: I see, but only the images are too dark. The GUI components looks good, no need to gamma correct them.

Comment: it's the mid ranges that are getting you though. You may be used to looking at "incorrect" but still decent looking GUI components when the monitor is off as a whole. If this problem is with all images you see, then this is probably the case. Consider that on average images are viewable in contrast with GUI components, otherwise *everybody* would complain and the trend would self correct; sites aren't using special dark images just for you. :) Another thing you can try is, when possible, choosing darker background colors for better contrast e.g. Hulus theater mode.

Comment: (or CSS overrides to darken bg colors of sites) Another way to state above point is images tend to lie in the region that is off the most with incorrect gamma, while GUI components are often bright or dark extremes, or even if they are in the middle it is acceptable when they are off because they aren't "natural" looking components to begin with, and so it's hard to identify them as looking "wrong". There's a lot of subtle visual perception at play in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to do CSS overrides of background colors on pages to make them darker.

However, consider that the problem is relatively unique to you rather than an Internet-wide ongoing issue of images being too dark, and this suggests your monitor may have a slightly odd color response. Some graphics drivers come with color adjustment preferences e.g.  gamma but I highly recommend checking out the free tool [Calibrize](http://www.calibrize.com) first before you start tweaking styles. It will help you calibrate your monitor settings.

Also before you start make sure your monitor settings and graphics card driver settings are neutral, double check just to be sure.

Also if you are using an analog signal e.g. VGA consider switching to displayport (digital), dvi-d, or hdmi instead. Sometimes it helps, although not always.